# При добавлении JpaRepository проект перестал запускаться

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Проект перестал запускаться (старт с помощью Spring Boot) после того как я добавил JpaRepository с ошибкой:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before flushing: ru.cadmy.finance.model.User
```

Есть две сущности.

Пользователь:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "USER")
public @Data class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 500)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String password;
}
```

И строка баланса:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "BALANCE")
public @Data class BalanceRecord {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
private User user;

@Column(name = "date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Type(type = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
private Integer value;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = true, length = 500)
private String title;
}
```

Проект запускался без ошибок до того момента, когда я добавил JpaRepository для строки баланса:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BalanceRecordRepository extends 

JpaRepository<BalanceRecord, Long> {
    @Query("from BalanceRecord b where b.user = :user and b.date >= :dateFrom and b.date < :dateTo")
    List<BalanceRecord> getBalanceRecordsForPeriod(@Param("user") User user, @Param("dateFrom") Date dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo);
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: А что у вас в БД ?

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка возникает из-за `CascadeType.ALL` - теперь вероятна ситуация, когда вы попытаетесь сохранить `BalanceRecord` с ссылкой на пользователя, у которого нет `ID`. Установите `CascadeType.NONE`.